# Is there specific way to remove an array element after 5 seconds with angular one

Tags: html, arrays, angularjs

I am looking for to develop notification disappearing feature on a system which use Angular one. Here's my HTML code:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <button ng-click='makeNotification("New Notification")'>Add</button>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat='n in notifications'>{{n.notification}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JS code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.notifications = [];
    $scope.makeNotification = function(notification) {
        var index = $scope.notifications.length;
        $scope.notifications.push({notification:notification + " " + index});
      $timeout(function() {
        $scope.notifications.splice(index, 1);
      }, 5000);
    } 
});
```

This works as I expected. but it seems to be bugs in that code. Some notification are remains without deleting.

Is there any other good way to do this? Below is jsfiddle I have created.
https://jsfiddle.net/niroshanJ/Lseaphrt/7/

Comment: Possible bug with indexing? As you delete (splice) elements from your array, you get less items in it, so you need to decrement your `index`, except that it's a bit harder to do with `timeout`. Shouldn't it be `$scope.notifications.splice(0, 1);`?

Comment: Do you want to remove all the notification or just the last one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably find that if several notifications are added within a few seconds there will be some that don't get removed because `index` is pointing at the wrong position.

Rather than keeping track of the notification's position in the array, 
you'll have to keep track of the notification itself...

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.notifications = [];
    $scope.makeNotification = function(notification) {
        var index = $scope.notifications.length;

        // need to keep track of this rather than the index it's added at!
        var notificationObject = { notification: notification + " " + index };
        $scope.notifications.push(notificationObject);

        //preserve context by wrapping the function that will be called by $timeout
        var timeoutFunc = (function(obj){
            return function() {
                var index = $scope.notifications.indexOf(obj)
                if (index >= 0)
                    $scope.notifications.splice(index, 1);
            };
        })(notificationObject);

        $timeout(timeoutFunc, 5000);
    } 
});
```

**OR**

As others have noted you could just remove the first item in the array - much simpler.

Comment: Work like charm! Thanks buddy and merry x mas! :D

Comment: @Niroshan no problem. Merry Christmas

Answer (score 1):

You can use the toaster to display the notification instead of doing manual code for it. And it is quite simple. The toaster will automatically clear down the message after the provided time.

Please follow the below link for angular toaster:

https://github.com/Foxandxss/angular-toastr

**OR**

Optionally: To install with bower, use:

```
bower install --save angularjs-toaster
```

or with npm :

```
npm install --save angularjs-toaster
```

or using link scripts:

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angularjs-toaster/1.1.0/toaster.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0/angular-animate.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angularjs-toaster/1.1.0/toaster.min.js"></script>
```

Then

Prepare the call of toaster method:
// Display an info toast with no title

```
angular.module('main', ['toaster', 'ngAnimate'])
    .controller('myController', function($scope, toaster) {
        $scope.pop = function(){
            toaster.pop('info', "title", "text");
        };
    });
```

Call controller method on button click:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <button ng-click="pop()">Show a Toaster</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This is really helpful! :) I will try this out. But really appreciate if you can suggestion for my solution also.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to show notification would be to use any 3rd party module like toastr or notify. But, if you want to create your own then instead of using `splice` (which will remove only one notification if you create multiple at a time), you could just destroy the `ul`

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <button ng-click='makeNotification("New Notification")'>Add</button>
  <ul ng-if="destroyNotification">
    <li ng-repeat='n in notifications'>{{n.notification}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.notifications = [];
    $scope.makeNotification = function(notification) {
        $scope.destroyNotification = true; // intitalize it to true
        var index = $scope.notifications.length;
        $scope.notifications.push({
            notification: notification + " " + index
        });
        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.destroyNotification = false; // after 5 seconds, destroy the element
        }, 5000);
    }
});
```

P.S. I haven't tested this.

Comment: Thanks dude! with some modification your suggestion can be used. But it's not what I want. I will use third party plugin for notifications. But anyone can give a solution it will helpful to learning purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to use seperate Index for remove element in timeout function

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
        $scope.notifications = [];
        $scope.makeNotification = function(notification) {
            var index = $scope.notifications.length;
            $scope.notifications.push({notification:notification + " " + index});
          $timeout(function() {
          var Deleteindex = $scope.notifications.length-1;
            $scope.notifications.splice(Deleteindex, 1);
          }, 5000);
        } 
    });
```